# Syntax error: Expected end of input but got string literal 'ynet.co.il' at [9:5] on a class project

Tags: google-bigquery

working on a class project. we were asked to find the number of mentions in all the big news sites in israel.  I have a problem with the last part (in bold). The Syntax **error: Expected end of input but got string literal 'ynet.co.il' at [9:5]**

I would be really appreciated your help.

```
    REATE OR REPLACE TABLE
   `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media` AS
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
WHERE
  SourceCommonName IN ('israelhayom.co.il',
    'ynet.co.il',
    'walla.co.il',
    'haaretz.co.il')
  AND LOWER(TranslationInfo) LIKE '%heb%';

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
   `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media_person` AS
SELECT
  date,
  SourceCommonName AS domain,
  DocumentIdentifier AS url,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(person, r',.*', " ") AS person
FROM
  `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media`,
 
 UNNEST(SPLIT(V2Persons,';')) AS person ;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media_person_sum` AS
SELECT
  date,
  domain,
  url,
  person,
  COUNT(1) AS count_of_mentions
FROM
  `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media_person`
GROUP BY
  date,
  domain,
  url,
  person ;

SELECT
  person,
  SUM(count_of_mentions) AS all_mentions
FROM
  `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media_person_sum`
WHERE
  domain=
  'israelhayom.co.il'
    'ynet.co.il'
    'walla.co.il'
    'haaretz.co.il'
GROUP BY
  person`enter code here`
ORDER BY
  all_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  50;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media` AS
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
WHERE
  SourceCommonName IN ('israelhayom.co.il',
    'ynet.co.il',
    'walla.co.il',
    'haaretz.co.il')
  AND LOWER(TranslationInfo) LIKE '%heb%';
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media_person` AS
SELECT
  date,
  SourceCommonName AS domain,
  DocumentIdentifier AS url,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(person, r',.*', " ") AS person
FROM
  `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media`,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(V2Persons,';')) AS person ;
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media_person_sum` AS
SELECT
  date,
  domain,
  url,
  person,
  COUNT(1) AS count_of_mentions
FROM
  `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media_person`
GROUP BY
  date,
  domain,
  url,
  person ;
SELECT
  person,
  domain,
  SUM(count_of_mentions) AS all_mentions
FROM
  `static-beach-312816.56146_2021_class_materials.israel_media_person_sum`
WHERE
  domain IN ('israelhayom.co.il',
    'ynet.co.il',
    'walla.co.il',
    'haaretz.co.il')
GROUP BY
  person,
  domain
ORDER BY
  all_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  50;
```